# Trying to reverse XOR on a zlib compressed string causes header error

Tags: ruby, zlib

Sorry for the mess of chars in this questing. In my script I compress and XOR the data like this

```
buff2 = Deflate.deflate(buff)
buff3 = ''

buff2.each_char do |c|
  buff3 << (c.chr.ord ^ 0xFF)
end
```

After decompressing the string it looks like this

`x��=�0 @�=��<38�k7l�v�Х?H�!��rwZ����p    ��8#��;�ZDS)}0�b��J�s�qz>����� ĿD��+"���]��I8dS2����ۿ�e_���~���`

After XORing

`câ4Âñ=Ïó¿ÂXwÃÌÇNÈw/ZÀ·sÞñhW¥YHCßöÇÜ{jÄ¥»¬àÖÏz} Áé@rùß;@»^+ÔåÝùrR¢V~¶Ç¬ÍD0 $@Y ^FâW`

However when I try to reverse the XOR (in the same way) the string does look similar but it's missing the � that string looks like this

`²xË=Â0 @á=§<38±k7lvèÐ¥?H!¨rwZ¦·¼ïp       îþ8#;åZDS)}0 bÉJÆsqz>¿ëíæ Ä¿D¡Ô+"ú­]©I8dS2»ä°ÏóÛ¿¦e_¡¹æ~àè¨`

I tried to inflate it with zlib and it fails with `incorrect header check (Zlib::DataError)`

What am I doing to change the �s into actual strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a string via `''`, its [`encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#encoding-method) defaults to UTF-8: (or more precisely your [script encoding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Encoding.html#class-Encoding-label-Script+encoding))

```
buff3 = ''
buff3.encoding
#=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Which makes `<<` interpret the values as Unicode codepoints (which can result in multiple bytes)

```
str = ''
str << 200       #=> "È"
str.codepoints   #=> [200]
str.bytes        #=> [195, 136]
```

If you want to work on bytes, you should use binary encoding, e.g. via [`String#b`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#b-method) or [`String::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#new-method):

```
str = ''.b
str.encoding
#=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

str = String.new
str.encoding
#=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

In a binary encoded string, codepoints equal bytes: (and non-ASCII bytes are rendered as `\xnn`)

```
str = String.new
str << 200       #=> "\xC8"
str.codepoints   #=> [200]
str.bytes        #=> [200]
```

In addition, you can use the byte-based [`each_byte`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#each_byte-method) method which happens to return numeric values already: (so you don't have  to convert them via `ord`)

```
buff2.each_byte do |b|
  buff3 << (b ^ 0xFF)
end
```

Alternatively, you can use [`pack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#pack-method) and [`unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#unpack-method):

```
str = 'foobar'

enc = str.unpack('C*').map { |b| b ^ 0xff }.pack('C*')
#=> "\x99\x90\x90\x9D\x9E\x8D"

dec = enc.unpack('C*').map { |b| b ^ 0xff }.pack('C*')
#=> "foobar"
```

`C` means "8-bit unsigned" and `*` denotes multiple occurrences.

If you just want to flip the bits, there's also [`Integer#~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Integer.html#%7E-method):

```
[102].map { |b| b ^ 0xff } #=> [153]
[102].map { |b| ~b }       #=> [153]
[102].map(&:~)             #=> [153]
```